# module not found error whle using librosa keyword

Tags: decorator, numba, librosa

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'numba.decorators'
File "C:\Users\prasa\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\Untitled-1.py", line 3, in 
import librosa

Answer (score 1):

Install a previous version of `numba` since the newest versions deleted the `decorators` module.

you can use `pip install numba==0.48`